# Ansible win_find command not listing files in D drive - failed to check some files, these files were ignored and will not be part of the result output

Tags: ansible

I have below Ansible (2.9.6 ) task to list the files in windows machines, some machine it works. for some server its giving warning not listing any files. any help to resolve this issue?

```
---
- name: getdir
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Find direcotry
    win_find:
      paths: d:\
      recurse: no      
      get_checksum: no      
    register: result

  - name: Find direcotry
    debug:
      msg: "output {{ result }}"
```

**Sample output:**

```
TASK [Find direcotry] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: win_find failed to check some files, these files were ignored and will not be part of the result output


ASK [Find direcotry] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => {
    "msg": "output {u'files': [], u'warnings': [u'win_find failed to check some files, these files were ignored and will not be part of the result output'], u'changed': False, 'failed': False, u'examined': 0, u'matched': 0}"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the user you are running it with have access to that drive, to those folders? Does it exists on those hosts? Could you run your playbook in verbose mode and provide us the result? `ansible-playbook -vvvv playbook.yaml`

Comment: Yes, account  has admin rights on that box. tried `-vvvv` option not giving any more details

Comment: Could you post the output with the full debugger enabled?  

`$ ANSIBLE_DEBUG=true ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY=4 ansible-playbook playbook.yml`
  
There might also be some insight in the Windows event logs.  I would also create a simple text file on the D:\ drive on the server that throws the error, just to make sure there are files present and you can read them.

Comment: @wowbagger tried this step, it display power command its trying to execute, but no pointer for this error message. also I can create the file in d: folder, which means user I am using has permission to write file in D drive.